# Basic matrix multiplication in OpenCV for Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, matrix, multiplication

I'm probably being incredibly stupid here but I'm having trouble doing some basicaly Mat multiplication using OpenCV for Android.

I have two Mat's both of the same type, `CV_64F`

`mat1` has size: 3 rows, 3 cols
`mat2` has size: 3 rows, 1 cols

I want to multiply them to give the product `mat3` of size 3 rows, 1 cols.

I've tried using:

```
Mat mat3 = new Mat(3, 1, CvType.CV_64F);
Core.multiply(mat1, mat2, mat3);
```

But I get an error:

> CvException
>   [org.opencv.core.CvException:/home/andreyk/OpenCV2/trunk/opencv_2.3.1.b2/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1253:
>   error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays
>   have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op
>   scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function void cv::arithm_op(const
>   cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_OutputArray&,
>   const cv::_InputArray&, int, void (**)(const uchar*, size_t, const
>   uchar*, size_t, uchar*, size_t, cv::Size, void*), bool, void*)

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help in advance.

**EDIT:**
If it helps, the 3x3 matrix `mat2` is the result of `Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform` and the rest of the code is as follows:

```
Mat mat1 = new Mat(3, 1, CvType.CV_64F);
mat1.put(0, 0, 2.0);
mat1.put(1, 0, 0.5);
mat1.put(2, 0, 1.0);

Mat mat3 = new Mat(3, 1, CvType.CV_64F);
Core.multiply(mat2, mat1, mat3);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are basicly trying to perform the following operation now:

```
[ 0 ]   [ 0 1 2 ]
[ 1 ] * [ 3 4 5 ]
[ 2 ]   [ 6 7 8 ]
```

In here * is multiplication. A matrix multiplication cannot be done this way. Read on matrix multiplications [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29).

The operation you would like to perform is :

```
            [ 0 1 2 ]
[ 0 1 2 ] * [ 3 4 5 ]
            [ 6 7 8 ]
```

To get your code working make the following changes:

```
Mat mat1 = new Mat(1, 3, CvType.CV_64F); // A matrix with 1 row and 3 columns
mat1.put(0, 0, 2.0); // Set row 1 , column 1
mat1.put(0, 1, 0.5); // Set row 1 , column 2
mat1.put(0, 2, 1.0); // Set row 1 , column 3
```

### EDIT

Also, you're using the method `Core.multiply`. In the documentation of OpenCv it mentions:
The function multiply calculates the per-element product of two matrices.
If you are looking for a matrix product, not per-element product, see [Core.gemm()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-gemm).

The function `gemm(src1, src2, alpha, src3, beta, dest, flags)` performs the multiplication according to the following function:

```
dest = alpha * src1 * src2 + beta * src3
```

Basic matrix multiplcation (in your case) is done by:

```
Core.gemm(mat2, mat1, 1, NULL, 0, mat3, 0);
```

Comment: I got the matrices the wrong way round to begin with, as DarkRift pointed out. However, I need to multiply with the 3x3 matrix on the left, which I would expect to work as in your first example above, but with the matrices the other way around, as shown in the Edit? Cheers.

Comment: Your matrices are formatted properly now. However, it seems you're using the wrong method as well. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this now works. If I use `null` for `src3` though I get a `NullPointerException`, so at the moment I'm just using the identity matrix here until I work out why null isn't allowed. Cheers again.
EDIT: `new Mat()` works fine as `src3` so I'll go with that.

Comment: For `src3` you could use `Mat.zeros(rows, cols CvType)`:

`Core.gemm(mat1, mat2.t(), 1, Mat.zeros(rows, rows, MATRIX_TYPE) , 0, mat3, 0);`

Comment: Wow, this is so unintuitive. I've been scratching my head for the last hour wondering why my code wasn't working. Obv simple mat vec multiplication has a weird name and needs 7 arguments... -_-

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your 2 multiplied matrices : 
Core.multiply(mat2, mat1, mat3);

Comment: I've tried this and it gives me the same error somehow, although you're correct that I had them the wrong way round. Thanks.