# Matrix by vector multiplication

Tags: java, opencv

Simple question. I cannot find any solution!
This is ok:

```
Mat dst = new Mat();
        Mat a = Mat.ones(3,3,CvType.CV_32FC1);
        Mat b = Mat.ones(3,3,CvType.CV_32FC1);
        Core.multiply(a, b, dst);
        System.out.println("DST\n" + dst.dump());
```

But this leads to an error:

```
Mat dst = new Mat();

        Mat a = Mat.ones(3,3,CvType.CV_32FC1);
        Mat b = Mat.ones(1,3,CvType.CV_32FC1);

//neither this
        Core.multiply(a, b, dst); ///<<<< ERROR
//nor this works
        Core.multiply(a, b.t(), dst); ///<<<< ERROR
        System.out.println("DST\n" + dst.dump());
```

> OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is
>   neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same
>   number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in
>   cv::arithm_op, file
>   C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp,
>   line 1987

Please, help to find a solution. How can I muliply matrix by vector?

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168058/basic-matrix-multiplication-in-opencv-for-android ?

Comment: @SergeyS , oh. thanks! Have not found it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the opencv framework, but according to the error message, b in your second code sample seems to be a single row matrix. You need a single column matrix :

Try with b defined like this :

```
Mat b = Mat.ones(3,1,CvType.CV_32FC1);
```

Comment: this is the same as b.t() . I've tried.

Comment: Apparently this multiply method is one by one element multiplication, not the matrix multiplication you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct solution:

```
Core.gemm(a, b, 1, new Mat(), 0, dst, 0);
```

A bit improved from:

[Basic matrix multiplication in OpenCV for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168058/basic-matrix-multiplication-in-opencv-for-android)